# Selecting same ID but different in other columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi please help me in obtaining the results where custids that have different inputs must be included in the results. Please note that CustID that has the same input regardless of how many times, must NOT BE INCLUDED.

Sample Table

```
+------+------+
|CustID|Input |
+------+------+
|123   |A     |
+------+------+
|123   |A     |
+------+------+
|123   |B     |
+------+------+
|223   |A     |
+------+------+
|223   |A     |
+------+------+
|332   |A     |
```

Results:

```
    +------+------+
    |CustID|Input |
    +------+------+
    |123   |A     |
    +------+------+
    |123   |B     |
    +------+------+
```

Thank you!

Comment: pls. tag DBMS (MySQL, MS SQL Server, Orcle, etc) which u r using.

Comment: If you add another row with (123, A), do you still want 123 rows to be returned?

Comment: yes but 123 would just appear still twice because two entries for having A as input should be counted as one.

Comment: @MaryRoseVillanueva add some more sample data from which we could derive your exact problem & answer u.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want records where the distinct `Input` count is greater than one for the `CustID`. You also want to get distinct result rows in case of duplicates. So get rid of duplicates first, count within each `CustID` and keep the desired records:

```
select custid, input
from
(
  select custid, input, count(*) over (partition by custid) as cnt
  from (select distinct custid, input from mytable) m
) counted
where cnt > 1;
```

or

```
select top(1) with ties 
  custid, input
from (select distinct custid, input from mytable) m
order by case when count(*) over (partition by custid) = 1 then 1 else 2 end desc;
```

Comment: tried these scripts but this still counts CustID: 123 as 3 entries (A, A, B). There should only be two since same entries must be counted as one.

Comment: You must have made a mistake. As I `select distinct custid, input from mytable` in both queries, there are no longer any duplicates. Provided of course it's `'A'` both times and not, say, `'  A'` and `'A  '`.

Answer (score 0):

Can be done in several ways, e.g. using `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CustID, Input
FROM tablename t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM tablename t2
              WHERE t1.CustID = t2.CustID
                AND t1.Input <> t2.Input)
```

Or `IN`/`GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CustID, Input
FROM tablename
WHERE CustID IN (SELECT CustID
                 FROM tablename
                 GROUP BY CustID
                 HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Input) > 1)
```

Chose `SELECT DISTINCT` or just `SELECT` depending on the expected result if there are duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this one

```
    select CustID,input from my_table 
    group by input,CustID having max(rowid) 
in (select max(rowid) from emp group by deptno);
```

Comment: where does emp and deptno come from?